# Slack chat.postMessage attachment gives no_text

Tags: python, slack-api

When I try to add an attachment to my message I either only get the text or if I leave out the text I get "error": "no_text", is there any way to send an attachmet with chat.postMessage?

This is the python code I use for sending the message:

```
r = requests.post('https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage', params=json.loads("""
    {
        "token": "xoxp-mytokenhere",
        "channel": "C4mychannelhere",
        "attachments": [
            {
                "text": "Question?",
                "fallback": "Question?",
                "callback_id": "callback_id",
                "color": "#3AA3E3",
                "attachment_type": "default",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "question",
                        "text": "Yes",
                        "style": "good",
                        "type": "button",
                        "value": "yes"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "question",
                        "text": "Nope",
                        "style": "good",
                        "type": "button",
                        "value": "no"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
"""))
```

Based on the comment I went with the following solution:

```
r = requests.post('https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage',     params=json.loads({
        "token": "xoxp-mytokenhere",
        "channel": "C4mychannelhere",
        "attachments": json.dumps([
            {
                "text": "Question?",
                "fallback": "Question?",
                "callback_id": "callback_id",
                "color": "#3AA3E3",
                "attachment_type": "default",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "question",
                        "text": "Yes",
                        "style": "good",
                        "type": "button",
                        "value": "yes"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "question",
                        "text": "Nope",
                        "style": "good",
                        "type": "button",
                        "value": "no"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ])
    }))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to send a JSON string as your entire set of parameters to `chat.postMessage`.

`chat.postMessage` and other web API methods only support URL-encoded query or POST body parameters, so your fields like `token` and `channel` and `attachments` are sent as application/x-www-form-urlencoded key/value pairs instead.

To complicate things a little further, the `attachments` parameter actually *does* take a string of URL-encoded JSON data. Your JSON array needs to be URL-encoded and stuffed into that parameter.

Depending on your goals, you could either skip using `json.loads` and just pass that JSON string as your `attachments` parameter and `requests` will take care of URL-encoding it for you -- or you can use something like `json.dump` on a native Python array you build with the same attributes.